# Access website without browser

Tags: java, http, sockets, servlets, web

I am just learning java. I just want to make a simple application to access a web-site.
there is a website onto which i want to log-in through java:
and then interact with it through my interface, basically after log in, i would be writing in some text boxes and sending it.
I tried many places to do it, studied HTTP protocol but still cant make it.
can someone help me out?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Accessing a web site, logging in and interacting with forms on it is somewhat complex work, so it might not be the best choice for a first java project.

But if you want to do it, you should probably use [Apache HttpComponents/HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/).

There are useful examples at the above link as well, which may help you get started.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, After a bit of research i found that it is indeed something complex.